# C# namespace for extending another product

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces, naming-conventions

I am currently creating a Visual Studio extension my issue is figuring out the namespace. I know the convention is (< Company >.< Product >).< Feature > , my problem is that I have created a utility library that targets Visual Studio explicitly. How do I name this namespace?

```
using MyCoolCompany.VisualStudio.Utility;
```

or

```
using MyCoolCompany.VisualStudioUtility;
```

Comment: It's entirely up to you. Seriously. Either is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to follow the convention, it would be

`MyCoolCompany.VisualStudioUtility`

since your company created a utility for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio itself (thus the utility is the product).

But it's just a convention; not everyone follows it at all times - not even Microsoft! (So many namespaces in the .NET framework start with System and not Microsoft)